# Adding a custom field with different labels and values in grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a variable declared with the type as custom field in grafana, so I am having the option

```
Values separated by comma : 1234,89076
```

this will be displayed as variable name and then the values which does not make any sense to the user. Is there a way I can replace it with labels and internally uses the corresponding values ?

Answer (score 0):

If the dropdown is populated from query, It's doable. Just need to specify the label and value in the query as follows.

```
SELECT name AS __text, value AS __value FROM data
```

For other options also, this must be doable. I just don't know.

Reference: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/13210